# Applying styles onHover and onClick

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

[image]

I want onHover and onClick effects on this. Looking for neat and elegant solution with professional css styling.

[image]

Requirement: On hover of any of the above items I want to surround item with a box having grey color background.

and onclick I want to surround with a box having background color as text color, change text color to white and have a x(cross/dismiss) in the box. Clicking on x should bring it back to the normal state as depicted in image.

Current Code:

```
 export default class Summary extends Component {
    renderJobStateSummary() {
        const jobCountSummaryDiv = [];
        if (this.props.jobStateCount.size !== 0) {
            jobCountSummaryDiv.push('Summary: ');
            for (const state of ['Total', ...jobStatesPriorityOrder]) {
                if (this.props.jobStateCount.has(state) &&
                    this.props.jobStateCount.get(state) !== 0) {
                    const cssClass = `${JOB_STATES_CSS_CLASS[state]} clickable`;
                    jobCountSummaryDiv.push(
                        <span
                          className={cssClass}
                          role="link"
                          tabIndex="-1"
                          key={state}
                        >
                            {JOB_STATE_DISPLAY_NAME[state]}: {this.props.jobStateCount.get(state)}
                        </span>
                    );
                    jobCountSummaryDiv.push(' | ');
                }
            }
        }
        return jobCountSummaryDiv;
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="summary-panel">
                { this.renderJobStateSummary() }
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

constants.js

```
export const JOB_STATES_CSS_CLASS = {
    [FAILED]: 'state-failed',
    [RUNNING]: 'state-running',
    [COMPLETED]: 'state-completed'
};
```

Css:

```
.state-failed {
   color: red;
}

.state-running {
  color: green;
}

.state-completed {
  color: #999999;
}
```

A simple example on span with class combination of :hover and :active and on style border option combination of inset and outset would really help me to get this working. Please help with this example.

Comment: look into :hover and :active

Comment: hover and active doesn't give professional look which I am expecting. I need more finished and elegant css.

Comment: :active only operates when the mouse is down on the link. Basically its impossible to toggle the state of a button as you require using only css. You would need a simple js function to toggle an additional style class.

Comment: I am fine adding some js as well, but I need a professional look.

Comment: @LokeshAgrawal reading the question again, this is not a coding service site. You should give a shot at styling the buttons and pose a question if you get stuck. What you look for can be easily done by an html/css professional in a few minutes but the purpose here rather is to help other developers and not code for them.

Comment: I guess your lack of understanding of question is resulting into such comments. Cant you see the code which I already tried? If you would have given a proper thought in understanding a question then you wouldnt have commented and downvoted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While using css, you can use something like

```
.my-class:hover {'background' : 'red'}; // for hover functionality
.my-other-class:active {'background':'yellow'} // for click functionality
```

No need of any javascript here.
But to add you `x` mark, you can place your mark with `visibility : hidden`, and then on hover, you can change the visibility.

There you go!

Comment: onClick of item it should add x mark with background as red and onClick of x mark it should default back to the text without background and x mark.

Comment: In HTML, put your x mark there inside a span with some class/id and set its style to `visibility : hidden`, and then on hover of that id/class selector, change the visibility and it'll work.

Comment: sure, will try this once, I am looking for an answer with border option combination of inset and outset, will wait for that answer before accepting this one.

Comment: This didn't worked the way I expected it to work, it shifts every other item on the right, unnecessary animation and not a professional look. I wanted some elegant solution, active remains and disappears.