# Managing overflows in divs

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a list of strings

['failed', 'running', 'completed' ........ ]

I want to show these list items in a div like below.

[image]

I successfully coded this but the problem I am facing is when this list grows div starts getting congested. What I want is when first line in the div completes and is no longer able to accomodate any further items then a next line with a proper padding and spacing should be started in the same div.

Something like below (note that other styling is not applied in the image below and  image is just added for illustrating how I want lines to be stacked in a div on screen resize)

[image]

Any pointers here is really appreciated.

Detailed code can be seen [Applying styles onHover and onClick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46474732/applying-styles-onhover-and-onclick)

Comment: hint: `display: inline-block`

Comment: Please add the code that you have and is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try **[CSS Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)** for this with `flex-wrap: wrap` property, like:

```
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

Have a look at the snippet below:

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

ul li {
  border: 2px solid green;
  margin: 10px 20px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Running</li>
  <li>Completed</li>
  <li>Failed</li>
  <li>Failed on Dependency</li>
  <li>In progress</li>
  <li>Upcoming</li>
  <li>Is Not Started</li>
</ul>
```

Hope this helps and this is what you need.

Comment: How is it different from answer posted by brk?

Comment: @LokeshAgrawal It is using `flexbox` instead of `inline-block`. Flex is more flexible than inline-block. So to say.

Comment: @LokeshAgrawal Know more about CSS Flexbox - https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 1):

You need a parent and a child container. Each of these text will are wrapped inside a `span` which are placed inside a `div`

```js
let listOfString = ['failed', 'running', 'completed', 'failed', 'running', 'completed', 'failed', 'running', 'completed', 'failed', 'running', 'completed']
let _string = '';
listOfString.forEach(function(item) {
  _string += '<span class="itemText">' + item + '</span>'
})
document.getElementById("textHolder").innerHTML = _string
```

```css
#textHolder {
  width: 200px;
  height: auto;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.itemText {
  width: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id='textHolder'></div>
```

Comment: You agree with Rastogi?

Comment: @LokeshAgrawal check for browser support